# Treating 2D NSE with an $L^4$ contraction mapping

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

For divergence-free initial data $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$, the two-dimensional Navier Stokes equation is known to have a global mild solution. This fact is classical. However, a written-out proof is hard to find, with citations generally just being to Leray's thesis (which is in French).

But while reading the article

> Tarek Elgindi, Wenqing Hu & Vladimír Šverák, *On 2d Incompressible Euler Equations with Partial Damping*, 355 Comm. Math. Phys. 145 (2017). https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02530.pdf

the authors' arguments seem to imply that there is a striking and elementary way of establishing this. In the course of showing global existence and regularity for a PDE (2.3, where the 2D NSE is a special case $\nu = \epsilon$), they write

> We now proceed along the usual lines and write (2.3) in the form [of an inhomogenous heat equation] . . . and invert the linear operator, to get an equation of the form (2.8) [$u = \Phi(u)$, where $\Phi$ is an integral operator] . . . We then recall the embedding $L^{\infty}_t L^2_x \cap L^2_t \dot{H^1_x} \hookrightarrow L^4_t L^4_x$ and consider (2.8) as an equation in $L^4_t L^4_x$ in the spacetime domain $\mathbb{T}^2 \times (0, T)$ for sufficiently small $T$ such that $u \mapsto \Phi(u)$ is a contraction in $L^4(\mathbb{T}^2 \times (0, T))$. As the $L^2_x$-norm for the solution is non-increasing, this procedure gives a global solution by routine arguments. (p. 4)

Unfortunately, I found it difficult to verify the details of this (will put more below, but I didn't want to disturb people by putting it in the body), nor could I find much in the literature. Not many references treat the 2D problem in detail, and of the ones that do, many establish existence through Galerkin procedures. I also found other arguments, but they used different function spaces, often at high regularities ($u_0 \in H^1$ or greater), and did not always speak on global existence.

So, that led to **my question: is anyone familiar with a reference that contains details for this line of argument, establishing global mild solutions for Navier Stokes in $\mathbb{T}^2$ specifically through an $L^4_{t, x}$ contraction mapping and energy estimates?** From the language of the authors (``usual lines"), it sounds like the general road should be well-trodden.

Or (for anyone if they decide to read the details below), is there an approach that makes the contraction mapping argument go through? Perhaps a functional/Sobolev inequality that could introduce $T$ dependency in the $L^4$ estimates?

### The Details:

The Navier Stokes equation $$u_t - \nu \Delta u + \nabla p + (u \cdot \nabla) u = 0, \ \text{div}(u) = 0$$ can be rewritten as $u_t - \nu \Delta u = - \mathbb{P} \nabla(u \otimes u)$ (using the divergence-free condition and applying the Leray projector $\mathbb{P} : L^2 \to L^2_0$, which sends vector fields to their divergence-free components).

Then for an initial condition $u_0 \in L^2$, a mild solution $u(t) \in C([0, T]; L^2) \cap L^2([0, T]; \dot{H^1})$ is a divergence-free map satisfying $$u(t) = S(t) u_0 - \int_{0}^{t} S(t - s) \mathbb{P} \nabla \cdot (u(s) \otimes u(s)) \, ds = S(t) u_0 - B(u, u)$$ for all $t \in [0, T]$, where $S(t)$ is the heat propagator.

With the inhomogenous heat equation $u_t - \nu \Delta u = \text{div}(f)$, $\ u(0) = u_0$, we have the estimate $$\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2} + \Big(\int_{0}^{T} \|\nabla u(t)\|_{L^2_x}^2 \, dt \Big)^{1/2} \lesssim _{\nu} \|u_0\|_{L^2} + \int_{0}^{T} \|f\|_{L^2_x}^2 \, dt.$$ For instance, this can be proven with the explicit Fourier representation of $u$. So we have control of $u$ in $C^0_t L^2_x \cap L^2_t \dot{H^1_x}$. By the 2D Ladyzhenskaya inequality, this space embeds into $L^4_{t, x}$.

So the idea is to treat this as a fixed-point problem in $L^4$. It is no trouble to see that the bilinear operator $B(u, v)$ should extend to a map $L^4 \times L^4 \to L^4$. What *is* troublesome is a failure to control of the size of $L^4$ norm with respect to time.

Inspecting the proof of the energy inequality, we see that $\|u\|_{C^0_t L^2_x \cap L^2_t \dot{H^1_x}} \lesssim \|u_0\|_{L^2} + \|f\|_{L^2_t L^2_x}$ with constants independent of time scale. Thus it gives the bound $\|B(u, v)\|_{L^4_t L^4_x} \lesssim \|u \otimes v\|_{L^2_t L^2_x} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^4_t L^4_x} \|v\|_{L^4_t L^4_x}$, with an absolute constant.

So this only offers an estimate of the form $\|\Phi(u)\|_{L^4_{t, x}} \leq \|S(t) u_0\|_{L^4} + \|B(u, u)\|_{L^4} \leq C \|u_0\|_{L^2} + K \|u\|_{L^4_{t, x}}^2$, without any appearance of $T$. For establishing a contraction, this does not seem too helpful. My hope was for an inequality like $$\|\Phi(u)\|_{L^4_{t, x}} \leq C \|u_0\|_{L^2} + K T^a \|u\|_{L^4_{t, x}}^2$$ for $u \in L^4$, with $a > 0$ and $C, K$ being absolute constants. Then I could consider the closed ball $\{\|u\|_{L^4_{t, x}} \leq M \|u_0\|_{L^2}\}$ for some large $M$, and choose $T > 0$ sufficiently small in relation to $\|u_0\|_{L^2}$ that a contraction would be guaranteed.

Testing this with scaling relations didn't give anything. Attempts to modify the energy estimate proof to introduce a power of $T$ also introduced possible divergences, and made it difficult to remain in the space $L^4$. Estimating the $L^4$ norm directly led to some rather singular negative powers of $(t - s)$ in the integrals, which had to be dealt with and gave no improvements.

In short, I'm having trouble understanding how a small time $T$ can be chosen so that the map $u \mapsto \Phi(u)$ is a contraction. All the inequalities available to me seemingly lack that dependence on time.

(Philosophically speaking, I think my issue is that $L^4$ estimates always seem to lead back to the Ladyzhenskaya inequality. The $L^2_x$ term is fine, but $\dot{H^1_x}$ adds complications, and might cause issues pointwise in time. Hence, the integration in time is applied to keep things under control, which prevents it from being used to give a power of $T$. The space $L^4_t L^4_x$ is certainly a natural one, but only having integrability, as opposed to boundedness, makes the estimates more challenging.)